# Get attribute of Scrollable JQuery UI dragged Item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to get an attribute of a list item I am dragging between lists. The lists are being made dynamic using the JQuery-UI scrollable plugin.

The scrollable aspect of the lists is working, I am just having difficulty getting the attribute "grid" from my list item

here is my javascript.

```
    $(
    function() {

        $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
        }).disableSelection();

        $( "#sortable1" ).bind( "sortreceive", handlefinanceitemdrop);

        $( "#sortable2" ).bind( "sortreceive", handlelinkdrop);

    }   
)

    function handlefinanceitemdrop(draggingevent, draggingui) {

        alert($(".finance_item ui-sortable-helper").attr("frid"));

    }


    function handlelinkdrop(draggingevent, draggingui) {

        alert($(".secenareo_item ui-sortable-helper").html());
    }
```

Here is an example list line

```
<li id="sl6" class="scenario_item" slid="6">Sample Transaction - Expence - Normal - Monthly - 50.00 - 50.00<br></li>
```

Thanks

Comment: ui-sortable-helper is appended to the class name when the item is being dragged, hence the difference between my line example and the function above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to grab an attribute of the list item you are passing from one list to the other you can use your `draggingui` object to determine which is the current dragged element. So, instead of using `$(".secenareo_item ui-sortable-helper")` use `draggingui.item`. I set up an example with your code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8rKvn/1/

Comment: Thanks so much, and thank you for the example. What a cool site too. Actually, I'm smiling as that's all pretty awesome. Thank you.